# Rails 4: Pass a hash as a checkbox value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, checkbox, hash

Is it possible to pass a hash as a checkbox value?

My controller passes an array of hashes (@citations) and my view loops through this array and displays the values of the hash as shown below.

Here is my code for my form.

```
 <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
 <ul class="publications">
  <% @citations.each do |publication| %>
      <li>
        <div class = "PublicationString">
             <%= check_box_tag "publications[]", publication %>
             <%= publication[:title] %>
             <%= publication[:authors] %>
             <%= publication[:journal] %>
             <%= publication[:year] %>
             <%= publication[:volume] %>
             <%= publication[:pages] %>

        </div>
      </li>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add to profile" %>
  </div>

 </ul>
<% end %>
```

What I need to do is pass an array of hashes back to the controller and then for the controller to loop through the array, and for each hash create a new publication in my publications table (which has columns for each of the hash values).

Is it possible to pass a hash as a value of a checkbox?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not just pass the citation's id(s) and get them back in your controller then loop on it? (if the citations are not stored in the DB, please show us how you set the `@citations` variable)